# Kendo UI dropdownlist mobile scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-mobile

I am currently developing an application using Kendo UI. I use a dropdownlist like this

[Kendo UI dropdownlist](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/OGiN)

On the browser it work's fine. I can open the list an scroll with the mousewheel, but when I try to use it on a device with touch (tablet or smartphone) i cannot scroll in the dropdownlist.

How can i add a listener or something else on the dropdownlist, that this makes it possible to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

From here:

[Kendo Support Forum - Unable to scroll on iPad](http://www.telerik.com/forums/unable-to-scroll-on-ipad)

> To enable scrolling of the DropDownList ( popup in particular ) you
>   need to include kendo.mobile.core.js, kendo.mobile.scroller.js. Check
>   [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krustev/RZEga/), which shows how to enable scrolling in mobile
>   device.

The css from the fiddle:

```
.km-touch-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 200000;
  height: .3em;
  width: .3em;
  background-color: #333;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.4em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.4em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
.km-vertical-scrollbar {
  height: 100%;
  right: 1px;
  top: 0;
}
.km-horizontal-scrollbar {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
}
.km-scroll-container {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-margin-collapse: separate;
}
.km-android .km-touch-scrollbar {
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: That work's but this is not the mobile dropdownlist. It's the web drobdownlist. Here you can see the mobile and and the web dropdownlist: [example](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/anIX)