# kendo dropdown Ipad issue

Tags: ios, ipad, kendo-ui

I'm working with kendo 2014.1.318 in an asp.net MVC application : I use the wrappers.

I have an issue with the cascading dropdown on Ipad (IOS 8.1 safari)

The issue is not reproducible on an android tablet and on windows browsers, I tried ie9, chrome, firefox and safari for windows : no problem

So, here is the problem:

I have a first dropdown containing a list of brands.
I have a second dropdown with a list of models

First I select a brand 
My dropdown "models" is populated => ok

Then I select a brand with a few models

My dropdown "models" is populated but the popup is not painted: it's all white

[image]

But if I touch the popup a few time: the items appears

If I select a brand with a lot of models : no problem

So I think this issue only appears when the number of items in the "models" dropdown is not big enough to activate the scroll in the popup

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you considered updating to the latest version of the kendo suite? Also does the same issue occur if you put say Chrome into iPad emulation mode? If you have a demo available to test that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your answer, I was able to reproduce it with chrome ipad emulation mode.

I cannot update, this is an app that will be soon in production and we don't want to update now.

I can't show a demo either ...

But Using the kendo extention for chrome I was able to see that the Datasource is correctly set, but the html for the popup is not rendered : I have an empty "UL"

Comment: without seeing some code to try and reproduce the issue then it is difficult to say what the issue is. Best bet it probably to get in touch with Telerik Support and see what they can suggest. They are really helpful and respond with good solutions. Although they will probably ask for a demo project to try and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I found a solution

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found the issue, it was caused by the popup being rendered in the top of the page and with a webkit transform.

The issue was really caused by the scrollview in the popup, I had to do this :

```
var modelescombobox = $("#myddl").data("kendoDropDownList");
var scroller = modelescombobox.list.data("kendoMobileScroller");
if(scroller)
{
   scroller.reset();
}
```

here is one of the link that lead me to the solution : [Kendo UI dropdownlist mobile scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955147/kendo-ui-dropdownlist-mobile-scrolling)